# Trigger Events at design time c#

Tags: c#

I have seen many people being able to handle the events at design time. I have a dock panel, which when clicked expands to give a container panel where user can drop controls. I was wondering if i can get any help of how i can achieve this?

Comment: which tech domain is your problem? WPF or WinForm?

Comment: I am working in Winform

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13531/Targeting-Design-Time-Events-of-User-Controls) should give you a fairly good idea of how to achieve it.